# AWS Serverless Aurora MySQL

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, phpmyadmin, aws-aurora-serverless

I am new to AWS services. I am using serverless Aurora Mysql as my primary DB. I can connect to MySQL via command prompt and used my private VPC. now I have created one EC2 instance with which I want to access PHPMyAdmin of serverless.

I tried but it was not connecting. While I try with the normal Aurora MySQL it is working but with serverless, it is not working. Are there any other MySQL clients with which I can connect and use the GUI? Any help would be much appriciated.

Comment: " tried but it was not connecting." - its not very specific. Any errors? Does using mysql cli on the same instance work? Was regular aurora and serverless using same mysql version, with same settings, VPC, security groups?

Comment: @Marcin Yes, I am able to login to MySQL with cli on the same instance. I have updated my serverless creds. to the conf.inc.php file and tried login into PHPMyAdmin but it only redirects. Nothing happens. No errors as well. In fact, I did not find any article with a similar problem.